# Xamarin c# ListView binding not working , equivalent xaml is working

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, binding

As the heading states my ListView binding from within xaml works , but doesnt work in c#.

Here's the code snippet:
Xaml

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Records}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding}">

                </TextCell>
                       </DataTemplate>       
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

C#

```
            ListView lv = new ListView();
            lv.ItemsSource = ClassVMInstance.Records;
            var dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
            dt.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, new Binding("Records"));
            lv.ItemTemplate = dt;
```

**ClassVMInstance** is an instance of my ViewModel.

**Records** is an `ObservableCollection<string>`

The xaml version works fine , it shows the text , but the c# version just has empty list elements without the text.

(I tested this on the same page with 2 listview one xaml and the other c# , only the xaml one shows the text , but the c# version just has same number of list items but empty)

I am to believe that the itemssource property is working properly in code but the binding is not can someone help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
dt.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, new Binding("."));
```

Comment: hmm whats up with the '.' ? , It worked thanks , but i dont understand why.

Comment: "." is the binding syntax for the object itself, not one of it's properties.  Since you're binding to a string, "." means just display the string.  In your original code you were trying to bind to Records, which doesn't work because Records is your collection, not a property on each item in the collection.